# Check for unresolved properties in Maven Resources

Tags: maven, resources, filtering

Given the following property in src/main/resources/hello.xml

```
<test>${resolved.property}</test>
<test>${unresolved.property}</test>
```

With properties:

```
resolved.property=test
```

How do I validate, after going through mvn:resources filtering, if there are any unresolved properties left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [XML Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/xml-maven-plugin/) to validate your XML file after resource filtering has completed.

This plugin can validate XML files against a schema or even just check that they are well formed (which will be sufficient to verify that your XML files do not contain property tokens).

You declare the plugin like so:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>xml-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>process-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>validate</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <validationSets>
        <validationSet>
            <dir>... your xml dir ...</dir>
            <includes>
                <include>*.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </validationSet>
    </validationSets>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Note: the use of `<phase>process-resources</phase>` is important here since you want to ensure that validation runs **after** your resources have been filtered.