# maven local repository directories with dollar name - unresolved properties?

Tags: maven

Currently I am debugging an annoying maven situation in which a simple

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

complains

```
The POM for com.bitplan.java:com.bitplan.bobase:jar:${bobase.version} is missing, no dependency information available
```

So it looks like a property is not defined somewhere. But the relevant parent pom clearly has:

```
<properties>
    <bobase.version>0.0.2</bobase.version>
</properties>
```

What is more interesting is that I am not even referencing any relevant file with such a declaration directly.

In the process of this mishap in the local repository a directory:

```
./com/bitplan/java/com.bitplan.bobase/${bobase.version}
```

shows up. So I got curious and looked if there were more of these:

```
 cd $HOME/.m2/repository
 find . -type d | grep "\\$"
```

gives me some 27 results at this time e.g.

```
./net/sourceforge/htmlcleaner/htmlcleaner/${htmlcleaner.version}
./junit/junit/${junit.version}
./junit/junit/${junit4.version}
./org/hamcrest/hamcrest-all/${hamcrestall.version}
./org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/${commons.version}
./commons-io/commons-io/${commons-io.version}
./commons-io/commons-io/${commons.io.version}
./args4j/args4j/${args4j.version}
```

I only understand one of the cases - the commons.io.version one - that was a typo and I fixed it. All other variables should be dereferencing ok and there should not be any such directories.

**What causes this maven behavior and how can it be avoided?**

I only found one releated question:

- [Check for unresolved properties in Maven Resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45628169/check-for-unresolved-properties-in-maven-resources)

but that gave me no useful hint

**debugging**

```
find . -type d -name "*\$*" -exec echo -n {} \; -exec stat -f %Sm -t " "%Y-%m-%d {} \;
```

shows the last modification time of the directories. E.g.

```
./junit/junit/${junit.version} 2018-08-22
./junit/junit/${junit4.version} 2017-05-28
```

so in my case the issue seems to happen every once in a while.

Comment: This happens, the first time when you declare a dependency with the `<version>` set to reference a property, but the property is not yet defined in your pom file.

Comment: Sure - that is obvious. But why does it still happen when the property is already defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 mvn deploy
```

of the parent pom is necessary if the version of the pom has not been upgraded.

```
 mvn install
```

is not sufficient. The resolution of variables will be done on the "old" settings from the repository.

Comment: for the removal of the superfluous repository directories i have asked a question at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/470543/find-exec-to-remove-directories-with-a-dollar